# Matching character between characters

Tags: python, perl, unix, awk, grep

I am trying to match a character e.g. `}` in a c file but it shouldn't be between
quotes e.g. `"}"` or `"fdjskfhjds } 543897dhfhd92-()*&$"`.
How can I form the regular expression for doing this using grep?

What I have now that returns 0 matches is:

```
grep '"[^"]* { [^"]*"'
```

and the idea is match the character { that is between "". 
(I need the not ^ to get more double quotes matches in the meantime)

If it can be done easier using other standard unix tools, solutions are welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

Use lookaround assertions
`grep -P '(?!.*")\}(?!.*")'`

The example below finds only the "}" between "more" and "blah"

`echo 'blah"}"more}blah' | grep -P '(?!.*")\{(?!.*")'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your version of `grep` supports PCRE, you could say:

```
'(?<=[^"])}(?=[^"]?)'
```

For example,

```
$ echo 'foo}bar"}"baz}' | grep -P '(?<=[^"])}(?=[^"]?)'
foo}bar"}"baz}
   ^         ^      <== The carets denote the matched }
```

Comment: Note: when I tried this one it only works for `"}"` and not `"some}words"` when pasted into Ubuntu 13.10